# Multiple loops in Genesis

Tags: genesis-theme-framework

So I wanted to create two loops on my homepage. One that would display the page's own content, and then a grid loop straight beneath it for fetching the two latest posts from the 'news' category. I couldn't really find a way to do it so I hacked around until I got it working, but I'm not sure this is the right way to be doing things, can anyone tell me what improvements I can/should make to this code?

Here's a screenshot of what I have:
http://s18.postimg.org/knrq6sert/2013_11_13_22_55_58.png

Theme: Metro
Template: page-home.php

```
//* Add support for Genesis Grid Loop
//remove_action( 'genesis_loop', 'genesis_do_loop' );
add_action( 'genesis_loop', 'child_grid_loop_helper' );

function child_grid_loop_helper() {
    if ( function_exists( 'genesis_grid_loop' ) ) {

        global $post;

    // arguments, adjust as needed
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => 2,
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'paged'          => get_query_var( 'paged' )
    );

    /*
    Overwrite $wp_query with our new query.
    The only reason we're doing this is so the pagination functions work,
    since they use $wp_query. If pagination wasn't an issue,
    use: https://gist.github.com/3218106
    */
    global $wp_query;
    $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
        genesis_grid_loop( array(
            'features' => 0,
            'feature_image_size' => 0,
            'feature_image_class' => 'alignleft post-image',
            'feature_content_limit' => 0,
            'grid_image_size' => 0,
            'grid_image_class' => 'alignleft post-image',
            'grid_content_limit' => 100,
            'more' => __( '[Continue reading...]', 'genesis' ),
        ) );
    }
}

//* Remove the post meta function for front page only
remove_action( 'genesis_after_post_content', 'genesis_post_meta' );

genesis();`
```

Two things I have not figured out yet.

1. How to change the headings of the grid loop from `<h2>` to `<h3>`. I had to style the `<h2>` on that screenshot so that they would be 1.5 rem rather than the default 3 rem. But ideally they would be `<h3>`.
2. How to remove the post author from those two posts in the grid loop.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You are using `page-home.php` instead of `home.php` which comes with the (v 1.0) child theme. Are you using a static home page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think both issues can be solved by altering what's happening inside the loop. The code you've posted are the arguments that are used for the query. There is a `while` loop which then goes through the results of the query and displays them. Try to find `while ($wp_query->have_posts()): $wp_query->the_post();`. Between this and `endwhile;` the results are displayed. There you'll find `echo get_the_author()`. If you remove that, the author won't be displayed. You can also alter the styling of the headers there.

Comment: So how would you do the alterations specifically within the Genesis framework?

Comment: I don't know the genesis framework, but if there's a query which outputs posts, there's definitely a `while` loop. Did you find it? It should be in the template which is used to display your page.

Comment: The Genesis framework handles the loop in the parent theme. There are ample Genesis specific hooks to allow filters and actions to control the result of loops. You can write your own custom WP_Query, but once you get used to it, it is often easier to use Genesis to do it. The `genesis_grid_loop()` function came about because child theme designers found they were often creating templates that feature one or more posts and then have the rest appear in a (normal) grid of posts.